# MongoDb relationship

Tags: c#, mongodb

In my Domain layer, I have the following two Entities for mongodb collections

```
public class League
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string LeagueName { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectId> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Teamname { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Service layer

```
private static IEnumerable<ObjectId> GetTeamsNotInSeason(Season season, IEnumerable<Team> teams )
    {
        var teamsInSeason = season.Leagues.Where(x => x.Teams != null).SelectMany(x => x.Teams).ToList();
        return teams.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Select(x => x.Id).Except(teamsInSeason);
    }
```

So each League has a list of Teams, referencing use ObjectId. But that means in my service layer it needs to know about ObjectId, hence I have to have a mongoDb reference in there. So my question is, do you have to store relationship references as a type of ObjectId, What is the normal standard for relationships in mongodb? Within c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoe need to analyze first the reads vrs the writes that you are going to have in the  database.

**Some basic rules:**

If you'll perform more reads than writes then embed as much as you can, that will improve read performance and allow to read data in a single call to the database. The choice embed or not is usually made on how data will grow, change over time and how you gonna query it.

Consider de-normalization of data for fast querying, sometimes duplicated name on other collection is not that bad as long you avoid to do multiples queries to the database.

**other notes:**

Denormalization always add some overhead to writes, but increase read speed. For your case I assumed will be more reads than writes and heavily used denormalization.

When reading data consider excluding fields from object when you no need them, proyections doesn't work very well on c# using linq but there are some workarounds for this particular issue so just be aware of it.

**EDIT:**
if you plan to have more reads than writes probably you can have a single collection with all the imofrmation.

```
public class League
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string LeagueName { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The best datatype to creating references between objects is **ObjectId**, however I'd be great for you to check the escenarios for data [modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/) in the case you haven't looked at it.

Comment: Ok so in this example I have Leagues which contain teams, now team names can change over time, so team needs to be a collection in its own right? So two collections League and Teams. Teams can be part of many leagues or none, Leagues always have list of teams. What datatype and how exactly do I set this relationship up?

Comment: if you'll have more read than writes it's more convenient to have a list of teams inside a league.

Comment: That makes sense but what I want to know is when I have a relationship, what datatype is the best practice, Now a League belongs in a Season. Each Season there is a numbers of leagues which teams get added to. So Teams need to be a collection in there own right and leagues need to contain a list of ids, What datatypes and kind of list (array, Ienumerable, List, Collection) do I need to use to represent that a league has a list of teams

Comment: Got you the best datatype is objectId d

Comment: Ok cool and finally (Sorry about this) What kind of collection? List<ObjectIds>? InEnumerable<ObjectId>? Something else?

Comment: that's more related on the C# side, also is more on your preference as a developer and it's depends on what you are developing at that moment, IEnumerable<T> is faster but simpler on the other side List<T> is very convenient for all the features OOB.

Comment: And one more thing finally, this means that all of my Entities require knowledge of MongoDb to use ObjectId, fine but my service layer that gets those entities from the repositories and then maps them to models to return to a UI, this means my service layer will also need knowledge of MongoDb to use ObjectId?

Comment: not necessarily, I had the same dilema some time ago, why do i need to expose objectId and polute my code with mongoDB dependencies right? well you can use convention over connfiguration and leave your objectId as string and let the driver to make a cast for you!

Comment: post another question I'll make the approach more clear on that

Comment: So when storing in mongoDb if it sees a field called "Id" it will convert it from a string to ObjectId? Sorry about this, completely new to mongoDb, EDIT - Going to make a new question for this now